# Are convex hulls of closed sets also closed?

Tags: convex-analysis

If $X$ is a compact set in $\mathbb R^n$, how can we show that $\operatorname{conv} X$ is compact as well? 
Can we say something similar without assuming boundedness, i.e., are convex hulls of closed sets also closed?

Comment: Does Carathéodory's theorem (convex hull) has any hints here?

Comment: As demonstrated in the answers below, it is not true that the convex hull of a closed set is closed. Regarding necessary and sufficient conditions for the convex hull of an unbounded closed set to be closed, this [note](http://www.emis.de/journals/JCA/vol.6_no.2/j194.ps.gz) may be of use.

Comment: Thank you, Hagen von Eitzen and Matt Rosenzweig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to prove that a point in the convex hull of a set in $\mathbb R^n$ is actually a convex combination of at most $n+1$ points, by a natural induction.

Then the convex hull is the continuous image of the cartesian product of $n+1$ copies of your set and the $n$-simplex, which is compact. A continuous image of compact is compact.

Comment: The fact you mention in your first paragraph is Caratheodory's theorem. In the second paragraph I think you need the cartesian product of $n+1$ copies of the set and an $n$-simplex.

Comment: @RobArthan, thanks for the reference to Cartheodory: I hadn't realized this fact was due to him! (And thx for noting the typo!!!)

Comment: garret: my pleasure! are you sure you need an $(n+1)$-simplex rather than just an $n$-simplex?

Comment: @RobArthan :) :)

Comment: Thank you, Paul Garrett and RobArthan

Answer (score 19):

The convex hull of $\{\,(x,y)\mid x^2y=1\,\}$ is not closed in $\mathbb R^2$ (it is the open upper half plane).